# Somente requisão GET funciona, POST,PUT e DELETE esta bloqueado

Tags: asp.net-web-api, cors

estou implementando o EntityFramework em um sistema que é baseado em selects, insert… Quando faço uma requisição POST ou PUT esta dando segunte erro. O metodo get esta funcionando normalmente.
.net 4.7.2

Pelo Swagger funciona, Postman funciona, pela front(AngularJS) da erro

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
>   ‘http://localhost:56223/fechacaixa/fecharcaixa’ from origin
>   ‘http://localhost:9090’ has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to
>   preflight request doesn’t pass access control check: It does not have
>   HTTP ok status.

ja tem as tags no web.config

```
<customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
  </customHeaders>
```

Comment: Dê uma olhada nessas respostas: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18619656/enable-cors-in-web-api-2

Comment: Resolvido com a sua resposta, muito obrigado